# Change zsh tab size

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I wanted to change the tab size (the amount of spaces a tab uses) used in my terminal, but it didn't work.
I then found out, that my shell (zsh) inserts a fixed amount of 8 spaces instead of a tab.
I was able to change the tab size in commands like `echo '\t.'` to 4 by doing:

```
tabs 4
```

But I could not figure out how to change the amount of spaces zsh inserts.
Is there some way to change this?

Comment: You mean in the line editor when you press Ctrl+V TAB for instance to insert a literal tab character in the command line instead of triggering completion?

Comment: In that case, you can't change it, tabstops are hardcoded to be every 8 columns in the code. I find it's the same in `bash` (readline), `tcsh`, `ksh93`. In `mksh`, a TAB seems to be like 4 spaces (no tabulation, independent of the terminal tab settings). In `yash`, tabs are rendered as `^I`. In `fish` or `busybox` `sh`, I wasn't able to enter a tab in the command line. In Linux' tty driver line discipline, entering tab moves to the next terminal tabstop, but if those terminal tab stops are not 8 column apart, you'll see that backspace doesn't work properly for instance.

Comment: No, I mean for example when I write multi line scripts in the ZLE. I want my indentation tabs to be 4 spaces wide.

Comment: That's what I meant (zle is zsh's line editor). So the answer is no. I don't know of any editor or line editor that honours the terminal tabs as set by `tabs`. Those are hardly ever useful. Even to display tabular data with different tabstops (than the default of them being 8 columns apart), you might as well use the `expand` command than `tabs` on your terminal.

Comment: That is sad to hear. But at least the `echo` command and stuff works. Thank you for your help.